# Knockout JS Binding Update Confusion

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to KO and JS and have made the following test. I want to see the login button when `vm.authenticated == false` and the logout button when `vm.authenticated == true`. I see the title changing properly so I seem to be binding ok, but the KO `if` does not seem to be working. I tried to make `authenticated` observable but that did fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="../Scripts/libs/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/libs/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script>

    <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
    <!-- ko if: authenticated == false -->
    <form>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: userId"/>
        <input type="password" data-bind="value: password"/>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: login">Login</button>
    </form>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: authenticated == true -->
    <form>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: userId"/>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: logout">Logout</button>
    </form>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var vm = {userId: 'user', password: 'password', title: 'unsigned', authenticated: false, login: function () {
                    var vm1 = {
                        userId: 'user', password: 'password', title: 'unsigned1', authenticated: true, login: function () { }, logout: function () {
                            var vm2 = { userId: 'user', password: 'password', title: 'unsigned2', authenticated: false, login: function () { }, logout: function () { } };
                            ko.applyBindings(vm2); 
                        }
                    };
                    ko.applyBindings(vm1); 
                }, logout: function () { }
            };
            ko.applyBindings(vm); 
        };
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I tried to make authenticated observable but that did fix it.` Can you show that code, because `authenticated` absolutely *must* be an observable for ko to be able to respond to changes.

Comment: Also, what is going on with you binding? You have three calls to `.applyBindings` none of which are restricted to only part of the DOM. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, please simplify to a single binding and then give us the simplified code if that is not working

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjb2n/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

```
var vm = {
    userId: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    title: ko.observable('unsigned'),
    authenticated: ko.observable(false),
    login: function () {
        vm.userId = 'user';
        vm.password = 'password';
        vm.title('unsigned1');
        vm.authenticated(true);
    },
    logout: function () {
        vm.userId = 'user';
        vm.password = 'password';
        vm.title('unsigned2');
        vm.authenticated(false)
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And also note what ben336 said about how you define your binding.

Comment: +1 to this.  I'm answering from my phone do I couldn't write out the whole snippet, but this seems like what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks.Here is what I am trying to do. I would like to create a Single Page Application where I have a single view (HTML) and multiple view models bound to it based on some external events. So I created a little controller that managers this navigation. In the first view, I have a login form ...but after the user fills in his credentials and clicks the login button, the controller creates a new view model (via a factory) and re-binds to the same view. The second screen should show the use logged in as. The controller listens in to commands queued to it by the view models. Am I too far off?

Comment: @KhaledHikmat: I think your problem might be that you are trying to use an MVC pattern with a library (`knockoutjs`) that is designed for the MVVM pattern. [This](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/) link goes at least some way to explaining the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- ko if: authenticated == true -->
```

should be

```
<!-- ko if: authenticated -->
```

The if expression verifies the truthiness of a variable, not an expression.

See the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

for the

```
<!-- ko if: authenticated == false -->
```

you can use

```
<!-- ko ifnot: authenticated  -->
```

#### update

I hadn't noticed your triple binding right away.  You should register a single model object to be bound.  If you want a property to respond to updates, you can make it an observable.

Comment: Yes...thank you for your answer! I tried this variation and many others...but it still does not work. After I login, I do not see the logout button..I see the title changed though!!

Comment: @KhaledHikmat Are you sure authenticated has the value you think it does?

Comment: absolutely...I am logging to the console. I have been trying with this for about 2-3 hrs ...I tried everything. Then I reduced it to code snippet above so I can post it here.

Comment: Why are you binding 3 times with multiple objects?  Just create a single object and bind that.  If you need to change its properties, make them observables and update them

Comment: @KhaledHikmat were you able to resolve your problem?  I think if you combine Matt's code snippet with my if statements you should be able to get it working.

Comment: Hi Ben336, thanks. No...I was not able to. But please see my comment above regarding what I am trying to do. Perhaps this is not a good approach...please excuse my ignorance in JS and ko ...I am an old timer trying to get into the JS world. My actual project uses MS TypeScript as I find it a good stepping stone for me and I have not been disappointed so far.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the point of KnockoutJS.  The idea is to avoid having to replace all the data every time you want to make a change.  You have a single view model (or a single one for individual components of the system), which you can update over time.  If you have set up your observables, the view will change to reflect the model automatically.  So there's no need to create new models, the correct approach is to modify the existing model.

Comment: Well..like I said it is very possible that I am far off! But I don't think s single view model will do for the application that I am trying to build. Of course, I would not need multiple view models for the simple login and logout scenario above but I should be able to switch the view model when necessary and this is where the binding problem I am having with ko. Anyway, I will simplify the example and see if I can convey the problem a little better. Thanks for your comments and input.

Comment: Ben336, yes...basically the problem is that I could not bind two view models to the view! Once I took care of that, everything worked well. Thanks for your help and patience with me.

Comment: Ok great!  If one of our answers was helpful, it's encouraged to accept it (the green check mark on the right ). To show that it resolved your issue.